# Error Unexpected end of JSON input when looking at changes

Tags: java, node.js, json

So what i'm trying to do is getting what has been modified in a JSON file and the exact path to it. The thing is, that JSON file is getting modifed by another program. Everytime i run my second program modifying my JSON file, i am getting the following error. Do anybody know why would this happen and has a fix ? (Thiss error is only printed when using the program modifying the JSON file. I can also tell you that the modifier program works perfectly fine.)

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getCurrent (E:\letssee2\app\testor.js:5:31)
    at FSWatcher.fs.watch (E:\letssee2\app\testor.js:11:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1364:12)
```

I have the following :

```
const fs = require('fs') 
const diff = require('deep-diff')

const filepath = '../temp/listings2.json' // File to watch
const getCurrent = () => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filepath, {}))

let currObj = getCurrent()

fs.watch(filepath, {}, (eventType, filename) => {

const newObj = getCurrent()
const differences = diff(currObj, newObj)
var listings2 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../temp/listings2.json"))


if (differences == undefined) {
    return;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(differences[0]["path"][0]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(differences[0]["path"][1]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(differences[0]["path"][2]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(differences[0]["path"][3]))

var path1 = String(differences[0]["path"][1])

//console.log(`\n\n${path1}\n\n`)

var fullpath = `${String(differences[0]["path"][0])}.${String(differences[0]["path"][1])}.${String(differences[0]["path"][2])}.${String(differences[0]["path"][3])}`

console.log(fullpath)

console.log(listings2[(differences[0]["path"][0])][differences[0]["path"][1]][differences[0]["path"][2]][differences[0]["path"][3]])

currObj = newObj
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that the second program is writing the file correctly:*

Is it possible that the modification event is triggered **during** modification rather than after the second program is finished writing the file?

If this is the case, you can be lazy and ignore the errors and wait for a proper modification to finish as long as you are absolutely certain the other program will be modifying the file correctly.

or

You could also go about "de-bouncing" the detection as well. [more info on that here](https://thisdavej.com/how-to-watch-for-files-changes-in-node-js/#using-fs.watch)

`fs.watch()` and moreso `fs.watchFile()` can be tempermental to work with regardless due to the different ways OS's constitute a proper file change.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine with fs.watchFile() instead of fs.watch(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should start debugging by just printing or echoing the JSON file and looking for any errors before the parse commands. Post the file contents if you would like me to take a look

Comment: I can tell you that there are no problem with the JSON file, when i am manually modifying the file everything works perfectly, it is just when using the program that i'm getting this error. And also, i can tell you that the program isn't doing anything wrong.